# Rewriting an URL returns an error 500 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, rewrite, windows-server-2016

I've tried many steps into rewriting my domain to the IP:port combo that a node.js web server gives, but to no avail.

I've tried https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/, still 500. On Windows Server 2012 R2 it worked just fine, but on Windows Server 2016 it doesn't..

Any tips on what I should try?

I've done the usual Rewrite Proxy from URL Rewrite, using default options, to the IP:port. As usual, it returns a 500, probably due to the headers, so I did [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/), which was needed on both the OS's, and then restarted the webpage from IIS. On Windows Server 2012, that was enough, and the webpage loaded. On Windows Server 2016, it still returned a error 500.. I can link the web server, although I don't know how much that will help..

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed the steps you've tried. You mention you've "tried many steps", and then only list one blog source. Please clarify, and improve the question by including the specific steps you've tried and the outcomes for each one.

Comment: So, I've done the usual Rewrite Proxy from URL Rewrite, using default options, to the IP:port. As usual, it returns a 500, probably due to the headers, so I did [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/), which was needed on both the OS's, and then restarted the webpage from IIS. On Windows Server 2012, that was enough, and the webpage loaded. On Windows Server 2016, it still returned a error 500.. I can link the web server, although I don't know how much that will help..

Comment: Use the Edit button below the question to add this necessary information to the question itself. This allows people seeing the question to also see this important information at the same time without reading through a lengthy list of comments to get it.